# Como fazer download de arquivos linkados em HTML dentro de aplicação AIR?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, adobe-flex, adobe-air

Criei um aplicativo com Adobe AIR e joguei dentro dele o componente HTML que irá abrir a minha página desejada. O problema que estou tendo é que, dentro dessa minha página HTML existe algumas funções de download de arquivos, porém estas não funcionam por estarem dentro do aplicativo AIR.

Alguma ideia do que posso fazer para conseguir baixar esses arquivos da pagina HTML que está dentro do aplicativo AIR?

Com o código abaixo a página até abre o link de download, porém fica em branco, é aberto um *popup* porém o arquivo não é baixado e nem consigo visualizar este.

```
htmlContent.location = "minha url";
var htmlhost:HTMLHost = new HTMLHost(true);         
htmlContent.htmlLoader.htmlHost = htmlhost;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para o meu problema neste [tutorial](http://srinivasannam.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/air-html-popup-problem/), espero que sirva a alguém.

A solução consiste em criar, por código, um handler `onclick` para todos os links da página depois que ela tiver carregado, e usar `navigateToURL` dentro desse handler para abrir o link no browser.

Código:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:HTML id="htmlComp" width="100%" height="100%" location="http://www.rediff.com" complete="addEventListenersToLinks(event)"  />

 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

   private function addEventListenersToLinks(e:Event):void
   {
    var dom:Object = e.currentTarget.domWindow.document;
    var links:Object = dom.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
     if(links[i].target.toLowerCase() == "_blank" || links[i].target.toLowerCase() == "_new")
      links[i].onclick = linkClickHandler;
    }
   }

   private function linkClickHandler(o:Object):void
   {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(o.currentTarget.href),"blank");
   }
  ]]>
 </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```